SwiftUI AccessibilityFocusState not working in Lists
I have a view shown as a crouton (from bottom view) when tapping a button. I want to move accessibility focus to this view when shown but using AccessibilityFocusState only works if the button is NOT inside a List. If it's inside a list it does not work.
Is the List "absorbing" the focus event?
Here is the code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showCrouton = false
    var body: some View {
        List { // CHANGING THIS BY "Vstack" WORKS
            Section("Section 1") {
                VStack(spacing: 2) {
                    Text("Label 1")
                    Text("Label 2")
                }
            }
            Section("Buttons") {
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        showCrouton.toggle()
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text("Show crouton")
                })
            }
        }        
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .crouton(isVisible: $showCrouton, config: Config(title: "Test crouton", closeActionTitle: "Close"))
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func crouton(
        isVisible: Binding<Bool>,
        config: Config,
        dismissHandlerBlock: DismissHandlerBlock? = nil
    ) -> some View {
        modifier(
            SnackbarModifier(
                isVisible: isVisible,
                config: config,
                dismissHandlerBlock: dismissHandlerBlock
            )
        )
    }
}

struct SnackbarModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isVisible: Bool
    var config: Config
    var dismissHandlerBlock: DismissHandlerBlock? = nil

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            content
                .zIndex(0)

            if isVisible {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()

                    Snackbar(
                        config: config
                    )
                    .onClose {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
                .zIndex(1)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom).animation(.timingCurve(0.77, 0, 0.175, 5)))
            }
        }
    }
}

public typealias DismissHandlerBlock = () -> Void

extension SnackbarModifier {
    func dismiss() {
        withAnimation { isVisible = false }
    }
}

public struct Config {
    let title: String
    let closeActionTitle: String?
}

public struct Snackbar: View {
    @State private var isCroutonFocused = false
    private let config: Config
    private var dismissHandlerBlock: DismissHandlerBlock?

    public init(config: Config) {
        self.config = config
    }

    public var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 18) {
            HStack(spacing: 16) {
                Text(config.title)
                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                alignedButton
            }
        }
        .padding(30)
        .background(Color.red)
        .accessibilityFocusedMod(isFocused: $isCroutonFocused)
        .onAppear {
            isCroutonFocused = true
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    var alignedButton: some View {
        if let closeActionTitle = config.closeActionTitle, !closeActionTitle.isEmpty {
            Spacer()
            Button(closeActionTitle) {
                dismissHandlerBlock?()
            }
        }
    }
}

public extension Snackbar {
    func onClose(perform action: DismissHandlerBlock? = nil) -> Snackbar {
        var snackbar = self
        snackbar.dismissHandlerBlock = action
        return snackbar
    }
}

@available(iOS 15, *)
struct AccessibilityModifier: ViewModifier {
    @AccessibilityFocusState var focused: Bool
    @Binding var isFocused: Bool

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .accessibilityFocused($focused)
            .onChange(of: isFocused) { newValue in
                focused = newValue
            }
    }
}

public extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func accessibilityFocusedMod(isFocused: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            self.modifier(AccessibilityModifier(isFocused: isFocused))
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}


Did you get any solution? was focus getting changed for you? I also got stuck with focus change state issue.
